# S3 Target with SignatureV2 authentication requirement

Tags: vb.net, amazon-s3, sprightlysoft

I'm working with an S3 target that I think is requiring V2 signature authentication, but I have been unable for the life of me to get this working.
I'm using the Sprightlysoft AWS component.

```
'create an instance of the REST class
Dim MyREST As New SprightlySoftAWS.REST

Dim RequestURL As String
'Build the URL to call. Do not specify a bucket name or key name when listing all buckets
RequestURL = MyREST.BuildS3RequestURL(True, "s3target.com", "", "", "")

Dim RequestMethod As String
RequestMethod = "GET"

Dim ExtraRequestHeaders As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
'add a date header
ExtraRequestHeaders.Add("x-amz-date", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("r"))

Dim AuthorizationValue As String
'generate the authorization header value
AuthorizationValue = MyREST.GetS3AuthorizationValue(RequestURL, RequestMethod, ExtraRequestHeaders, TextBoxAWSAccessKeyId.Text, TextBoxAWSSecretAccessKey.Text)
'add the authorization header
ExtraRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", AuthorizationValue)

'call MakeRequest to submit the REST request
Dim RetBool As Boolean
RetBool = MyREST.MakeRequest(RequestURL, RequestMethod, ExtraRequestHeaders, "")
```

The error message I get is:

> "The AWS Access Key ID and Signature did not match your provided.
>   Please check your key and signing method"

According to errors and my research, it would seem that the target is requiring a v2 signature, and there seems to be a v2 signature function available, within the Sprightlysoft AWS component.

https://sprightlysoft.com/AWSComponent/Help/html/2605bafc-43dc-df45-7700-bd2fd74e1505.htm

```
Public Function GetSignatureVersion2Value (RequestURL As String, RequestMethod As String, SendData As String, AWSSecretAccessKey As String ) As String
```

I've tried to get this working, but I'm just guessing to how/where this needs to be used.  I wondered if someone may know how to use this so I can authenticate properly, if this is indeed the missing piece of the puzzle.

Comment: *the target is requiring a v2 signature* ... there are no S3 regions that **require** V2.  If you are talking about genuine Amazon S3 (not some other service that is "compatible,") then all S3 endpoints support V4, and the older regions *also* support V2... so V2 is not ever "required."